# Flask Python Function in Html

Tags: python, html, flask

Hello i am making project and i got stuck there, i am getting Nothing when doing this 
Python Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request ,escape
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
        return render_template("ddd.html")
@app.route('/weather', methods=['POST'])
def weather():
        selected_city = request.form.get('manu')
        r = requests.get(selected_city,timeout=10)
        c = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
        all_items = soup.find_all("div", {"class","cont25"})
        time_items = soup.find_all("div",{"cass","24_in"})
        return render_template("weather.html",all_items=all_items,time_items=time_items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}


<form method="POST" action="weather">
    <select name="manu" id="the_select" style="margin-right: 6px;">
        <option>აირჩიე ქალაქი</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/abastumani/აბასთუმანი">აბასთუმანი</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/akhaltsikhe/ახალციხე">ახალციხე</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/batumi/ბათუმი">ბათუმი</option>
</select>
    <p><input value="ძიება" type="SUBMIT"></p>
</form>

<ol>
{% for items in all_items %}
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"t25"}).text}}</li>
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"t252"}).text}}</li>    
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"tmp25"}).text.strip()}}</li> 
{% for items in time_items %}
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"info_txt"}).text}}</li>
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"info_tmp"}).text}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>


{% endblock %}
```

And in and ol is clear Nothing is output....
i have tryed many thing but getting errors and other things 
Thank You

Comment: Can you add an example of the content of `selected_city`  args you may expect ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus anything in html option value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put put weather.html in directory called templates. And here is the file I modified work perfectly. Change your app.py like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request ,escape
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])

def home():
    return render_template("weather.html")
@app.route('/weather', methods=['POST'])
def weather():
        selected_city = request.form.get('manu')
        r = requests.get(selected_city,timeout=10)
        c = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
        all_items = soup.find_all("div", {"class","cont25"})
        time_items = soup.find_all("div",{"cass","24_in"})
        return render_template("weather.html",all_items=all_items,time_items=time_items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

and change your weather.html (remember to put it in templates folder) like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="weather">
    <select name="manu" id="the_select" style="margin-right: 6px;">
        <option>აირჩიე ქალაქი</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/city/abastumani/აბასთუმანი">აბასთუმანი</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/city/akhaltsikhe/ახალციხე">ახალციხე</option>
        <option value="https://amindi.ge/city/batumi/ბათუმი">ბათუმი</option>
</select>
    <p><input value="ძიება" type="SUBMIT"></p>
</form>

<ol>
{% for items in all_items %}
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"t25"}).text}}</li>
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"t252"}).text}}</li>    
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"tmp25"}).text.strip()}}</li> 
{% for items in time_items %}
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"info_txt"}).text}}</li>
    <li>{{items.find("div", {"class":"info_tmp"}).text}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

[image]